# How to Install IIS with NSIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, nsis

I am building an installer which installs and configures iis and php.

My iis-install.bat file:

```
Start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-Security;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;IIS-CGI
```

My setup.nsi:

```
Section -iis_installation
  installIIS:
  ;MessageBox MB_YESNO "Allow To Install IIS?" /SD IDYES IDNO permissionModifier
    File "iis-install.bat"
    nsExec::Exec "iis-install.bat"
  endInstall:
SectionEnd
```

Both the bat file and setup.nsi are in same folder.

Problem:
When i compile and run the setup.exe file it will giv an error as below:

**"atempt was made to load the progrom in an incorrect format"**

And other batch files run properly with nsis except iis-install.bat why?

Please help to solve the issue or suggest any other idea to install iis with nsis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a batch file if it only contains a single command? And the wait parameter for start is /WAIT not /w!

Try `nsExec::Exec '"c:\full\path\to\pkgmgr.exe" /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;...;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;IIS-CGI'`

Comment: Thanks For reply, But even after trying your alternatives, its yeilding the same result. Can you please suggest me any other ways to install iis via NSIS...?

Comment: I assume your installer is running elevated? Have you seen this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/796396fa-977d-4709-8ef3-a125c6ed68ca/installing-iis7-with-32bit-version-of-pkgmgrexe-fails-on-64bit ?

Comment: If you dont mind, Please elaborate "elevated". And I am looking at the page of link posted by you, I will reply you in few minutes...

Comment: I am using windows 7 64bit, As your link states the usage of DISM for installation of iis, Can you please tell that how my command for iis installation changes with DISM.

Comment: Elevated means that you have "RequestExecutionLevel admin" in your .nsi and you get a UAC dialog that you accept so that the installer process is running as a administrator. I don't know anything about DISM or IIS for that matter...

Comment: Ya, Its running at admin level so what?